# Deny direct request using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, request, using

Is there any way to use .htaccess to deny direct Request to a specific part of my website e.g. www.example.com/XXXXX

I only want to allow Referer only to XXXXXX. I know that I have to use HTTP_REFERER somehow to accomplish my goal but currently I am using other .htaccess rules and not sure how to combine all rules together. This is what I have right now in my .htaccess

> Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine
>   on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$
>   /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

Answer (score 0):

First of, am not sure i understand correctly your question, but i give it a try anyway.

Currently you have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What you'd need in addition is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://your-domain\.tld/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule XXXXXX/(.*)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

.htaccess `RewriteRule`'s are checked in the order they occur, so you might want to do something like this, although I stand corrected because haven't had a chance to check if it'd work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://your-domain\.tld/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule XXXXXX/(.*)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

That is, first check if it's an argumented file named index.php which should be rewritten, if not (no `L` flag), go on for the next rule first grabbing a new condition, then if the rule validates, restrict access (throw HTTP 403).

Does this make sense?
Anyway, please experiment with the above .htaccess example because as I said, I couldn't test it.